# ListView binding only updating UI when scrolling

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have a Xamarin Forms project, using ViewModels and XAML binding. I have a particular ListView that is bound to an ObservableCollection of a particular object.

On-click I am trying to change the colour of the button, I can see that the event is firing, and the PropertyChanged is working as expected, however the button doesn't change colour until I scroll down the ListView so that it no longer is in view, then scroll back up to it. Once I scroll back, I assume this triggers some kind of "Let me know your state so I can display you" event which is then picking up the change.

Below is my XAML:

```
<ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewItems}" Margin="0,20,0,0" RowHeight="130" SeparatorVisibility="None" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row ="0" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Button Command="{Binding HeatClickedCommand}" Margin="5,10,5,10" HorizontalOptions ="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="{Binding color_hex}" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="{StaticResource LightTextColor}" FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding heat_title}"></Button>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

You may notice that I am using `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"`
 which perhaps may have sometime to do with this issue, the reason behind this is explained in a previous SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983049/xamarin-listview-bound-to-observablecollection-changing-at-random).

Essentially having the default CachingStrategy caused unexpected results.

Comment: Did you implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on the models inside your collection?

Comment: Well.. This is embarrassing, Gerald you've come to the rescue again. Such a simple fix, I really should have noticed but assumed it would have complained about implementing PropertyChangedEventHandler without the interface. Once again, please put an answer and i'll give you the rep you deserve

Comment: No problem! Updated it to an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update the view immediately, you will have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your model. With this interface, whenever a property value changed, it will notify the UI and update accordingly.

The reason it is updated whenever you scroll is because the cell is repainted or even repopulated altogether.

Do not mistakenly think that using a `ObservableCollection` will do that, since that only reflects updates in the collection structure, not the models in it.